# Heroku ffmpeg buildpacks for video uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, heroku, ffmpeg, paperclip

Is there a proper way to get heroku ffmpeg installed and running so that my users can upload videos in my rails app?

Tried the Heroku references on the topic which led to my app running the heroku error check logs page...

I know there has to be some installation I have to pass but don't seems to find anything on it - Please help with links or ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

> users can upload videos

We've had it working on Heroku before; we used [`paperclip-ffmpeg`](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg) (which is now [`paperclip-av-transcoder`](https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder)) with the actual [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem.

Whilst I can't provide any information about the buildpacks, I *can* share how we were able to get [video uploading working on Heroku](https://github.com/joehilton/hpvideos/blob/master/app/models/attachment.rb)...

```
#app/models/attachment.rb
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :attachment,
    styles:     { thumb: { geometry: "100x100#", format: 'jpg', time: 10}, medium: { geometry: "300x300#", format: 'jpg', time: 10} },
    processors: [ :transcoder ]
end
```

As long as the `paperclip-av-transcoder` gem installs (ensure you've got it in your `Gemfile`), this should allow you to store the videos - and images - you need.

Comment: You don't have to setup buildpacks so that Heroku can process the video files? Gonna try the setup in your example - Thanks!

Comment: I'm needing to create a procfile for heroku - I'm guessing?

Comment: This is the error Im getting now: Av::UnableToDetect (Unable to detect any supported library) @RichPeck

Comment: Oh osrry, I just woke up. If you're using unicorn or something, you'll need a procfile, otherwise it should be alright

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034148/getting-ffmpeg-to-work-with-heroku?rq=1 says to use build packs to install ffmpeg on heroku - I'm confused as to why I keep getting the AV error if I've set up the heroku ffmpeg buildpack setup - super frustrating at this point...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92463/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-manuel-quintanilla).

Comment: What about the :medium?

Comment: Added a Procfile / Heroku ps set to 1 / and the buildpacks

Comment: You should update your question so others can find it if they google it - it seems like a big problem

Answer (score 1):

**Got heroku Video uploads to work!**

```
Video model:
    has_attached_file :video, styles: {
        :medium => {
          :geometry => "640x480",
          :format => 'mp4'
        },
        :thumb => { :geometry => "160x120", :format => 'jpeg', :time => 10}
    }, :processors => [:transcoder]
    validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
```

Make sure you already bundled:

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'
```

Run the paperclip migration:

```
rails g paperclip model video
```

Be sure to add in post_controller.rb:

```
private

    def bscenes_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:video)
    end
```

Upload form:

```
<%= f.file_field :video %>
```

Show page:

```
<%= video_tag bscene.video.url(:medium), controls: true, style: "max-width: 100%;" %>
```

At this point you should get this error:

> Av::UnableToDetect (Unable to detect any supported library):

Go to your terminal and type in:

```
brew options ffmpeg
```

Then run the following to install ffmpeg:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libas
```

At this point video uploads will work locally

**Now for remote uploads you will need to setup** https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

After setting up Heroku buildpacks you may get an error:

> Av::UnableToDetect (Unable to detect any supported library)

You will need to create a Procfile in the root of your app directory more information about Procfile here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

```
touch Procfile
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Couple comments:
1. You don't need both `paperclip-ffmpeg` and `paperclip-av-transcoder`.
2. Add heroku ffmpeg build pack after Ruby buildpack using the command: 
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg --index 2
&& heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git --index 1

Comment: I added the build packs and removed paperclip-ffmpeg

Comment: When i tried to push up to heroku i get this error: Push rejected, error fetching custom buildpack

Comment: I am having trouble adding the buildpacks. What do you put on your Procfile?

Comment: I added "web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT" and it works.